# Como selecionar células específicas de diferentes planilhas e montar um novo dataframe com o R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tenho algumas dezenas de planilhas de Excel, com nomes padronizados e na pasta do projeto R, e gostaria de selecionar células especificas, com localização padronizadas entre as planilhas e montar um novo data frame.
Exemplo:

Na célula A3, tenho nome;
Na célula C5, tenho idade;
Na célula F4, tenho profissão;
Na célula F10, tenho a cidade;
Na célula J22, tenho Opinião sobre um produto.

Como posso fazer para montar um novo dataframe que me apresente as colunas:
NOME IDADE PROFISSÃO CIDADE OPINIÃO

e em cada linha os dados extraídos de cada planilha que está na pasta?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: As planilhas são `.xlsx` ou `.xls`?

Comment: As planilhas são .xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um colega no stack overflow em inglês conseguiu ajudar na solução desse problema utilizando o R base:

```
library(readxl) #carregar o pacote que tem a função read_excel

#A função list.files vai montar uma lista com todos os arquivos que tenham
##".xlsx" no seu nome e os coloca no objeto nomeado como "files".
#As planilhas estão em uma subpasta dentro do projeto. O argumento 
##"recursive = TRUE" varre as subpastas.
files <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)

#Preparar o banco de dados com número de linhas de acordo com a quantidade
##de documentos estocados no objeto "files", precisamos colocar a quantidade
##de colunas que vamos querer montar:
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=length(files),ncol=5))

#Nomear as colunas do banco de dados criado (de acordo com o número 
##de colunas informado anteriormente):
colnames(df) <- c("NOME", "IDADE", "PROFISSÃO", "CIDADE", "OPINIÃO") 

#Função para varrer as células selecionadas nas planilhas e inserí-las 
##no banco de dados criado:
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  raw_read <- read_excel(files[i])

#o R reconhece a localização dos dados dessa maneira: 
##[NÚMERO DA LINHA, NÚMERO DA COLUNA]
  df[i,] <- c(raw_read[3,1],   #célula A3
              raw_read[5,3],   #célula C5
              raw_read[4,6],   #célula F4
              raw_read[10,6],  #célula F10
              raw_read[22,10]) #célula J22
}
```

[Discussão no stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192623/how-to-select-specific-cells-from-worksheets-and-assemble-a-new-dataframe-with-r)

Muito obrigado!

OBS: Se alguém conseguir resolver utilizando o tidyverse, eu agradeço bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é o código abaixo. Assume que corre na pasta onde estão os ficheiros.
Não testado.

```
library(readxl)
library(cellranger)

ficheiros <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
planilhas <- lapply(ficheiros, \(x) {
  nome <- read_excel(x, range = as.cell_limits("A3"))
  idade <- read_excel(x, range = as.cell_limits("C5"))
  profissao <- read_excel(x, range = as.cell_limits("F4"))
  cidade <- read_excel(x, range = as.cell_limits("F10"))
  opiniao <- read_excel(x, range = as.cell_limits("J22"))
  data.frame(nome, idade, profissao, cidade, opiniao)
})
dados <- do.call(rbind, planilhas)
```

Comment: Olá Rui, obrigado por colaborar. A primeira etapa ele realiza, monta a lista (como está em uma subpasta, acrescentei o argumento recursive = TRUE). Mas o lapply não está montando os vetores com os valores das diferentes celulas. retorna apenas com um valor. Sendo assim, não monta também o dataframe. Sabe o que poderia resolver? Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: @JeffersonRodrigues Imediatamente antes do `data.frame(.)` na última linha to `lapply` ponha `cat("nome:", nome, "\tidade:", idade, "\tprofissao:", profissao, "\tcidade:", cidade, "\tprofissao:", "\n")` e veja o que é que dá.

Comment: @JeffersonRodrigues Pode também tentar `ficheiros <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: Bom dia Rui. Obrigado pelas tentativas. Não funcionou dessa forma. Fiquei curioso para saber, nesse caso, qual seria a ação esperada da função cat? Vou colocar na resposta como foi resolvida a questão, com o R base, pela a contribuição de outro colega no stackoverflow em inglês.

Comment: @JeffersonRodrigues A função `cat` serviria para ver o que é que o `read_excel` leu, se é que leu alguma coisa, nada mais. E por favor poste o link da solução. Ainda bem que já está resolvido.

Comment: Coloquei a solução e o link na resposta abaixo. Muito obrigado!